# R plot(): Why does xlab only appear after quartz window size adjustment?

Tags: r, plot

When I use the plot() command internally in R, the xlab doesn't appear until I resize the quartz window. Why?

Reproducible example:

```
 plot(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3), xlab = "where are you?")
```

When I plot this I do not see the xlab until making an arbitrary resize of the window.

My sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[7] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] pROC_1.5.4         snowfall_1.84-4    snow_0.3-12       
 [4] glmnet_1.9-5       Matrix_1.0-12      languageR_1.4     
 [7] e1071_1.6-1        class_7.3-7        caret_5.16-24     
[10] reshape2_1.2.2     plyr_1.8           lattice_0.20-15   
[13] foreach_1.4.1      cluster_1.14.4     randomForest_4.6-7
[16] neuralnet_1.32     verification_1.35  CircStats_0.2-4   
[19] boot_1.3-9         fields_6.8         maps_2.3-2        
[22] spam_0.29-3        ROCR_1.0-5         gplots_2.11.3     
[25] MASS_7.3-28        KernSmooth_2.23-10 caTools_1.14      
[28] gdata_2.13.2       relaxo_0.1-2       quadprog_1.5-5    
[31] lasso2_1.2-16      ada_2.0-3          nnet_7.3-7        
[34] lars_1.2           rpart_4.1-1        waveslim_1.7.1    
[37] gtools_3.0.0       Hmisc_3.12-2       Formula_1.1-1     
[40] survival_2.37-4    foreign_0.8-54    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-5    codetools_0.2-8 iterators_1.0.6
[4] stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: Please add reproducible example, plus the output of `sessionInfo()` (this problem is probably specific to your OS and possibly version of R).

Comment: Try some experiments, like `quartz.new(4,4)` or `dev.new(4,4)` ,  followed by your plotting, and if the results are always the same, take a look at the r-sig-mac mailing list archives.  Weird stuff often happens with various flavors of Mountain Lion.

Comment: With `R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)` I don't get the problem you describe.

Comment: FWIW I've had the same issue for a while.